# Roboto supporting capital sharp s (ẞ)

Tags: roboto

According to this article, the german capital sharp s (ẞ) is official. (https://medium.com/@typefacts/the-german-capital-letter-eszett-e0936c1388f8)

Google's Roboto for Android is already supporting the ẞ:
https://github.com/google/roboto/releases/tag/v2.138

But the according Web-Font isn't:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto

Is there a way to get the capital s into the web-font, or when is Google going to support it?